# rowsum on a nested table in r

Tags: r, dataframe, rowsum

I have a complex data frame and a minimal example is as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(District = c("Adilabad", "Adilabad", "Adilabad", 
                        "Adilabad", "Adilabad", "Adilabad", "Adilabad", "Adilabad", "Adilabad", 
                        "Adilabad"), Subdistt = c("Adilabad", "Adilabad", "Adilabad", 
                        "Tamsi", "Tamsi", "Tamsi", "Tamsi", "Tamsi", "Tamsi", "Tamsi"
                        ), TRU = c("Total", "Rural", "Urban", "Total", "Rural", "Urban", 
                        "Rural", "Rural", "Urban", "Urban"), Level = c("District", "District", 
                        "District", "Sub-District", "Sub-District", "Sub-District", "Village", 
                        "Village", "Town", "Town"), No_HH = c(1277, 364, 913, 
                        1277, 364, 913, 117, 247, 614, 299)), .Names = c("District", 
                        "Subdistt", "TRU", "Level", "No_HH"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

which looks like this:

```
   District Subdistt   TRU        Level No_HH
1  Adilabad Adilabad Total     District  1277
2  Adilabad Adilabad Rural     District   364
3  Adilabad Adilabad Urban     District   913
4  Adilabad    Tamsi Total Sub-District  1277
5  Adilabad    Tamsi Rural Sub-District   364
6  Adilabad    Tamsi Urban Sub-District   913
7  Adilabad    Tamsi Rural      Village   117
8  Adilabad    Tamsi Rural      Village   247
9  Adilabad    Tamsi Urban         Town   614
10 Adilabad    Tamsi Urban         Town   299
```

Each subsequent column in a way is a kind of subset of the previous column.  I have to validate if the sum of Sub-District and District at the Rural, Urban and Total level.

For eg:  The sum of rows 7 and 8 is equal to the value in row 5.  Row 5 is a Rural Sub-Distrit.  As we extend the df, I have many rural sub-districts.  The sum of all rural sub-districts is given in the Rural District, which is row 2.

A minimal expected output will be as follows:

```
  District Subdistt   TRU        Level No_HH
1 Adilabad    Tamsi Rural Sub-District   364
2 Adilabad    Tamsi Urban Sub-District   913
```

364 is a sum of 117 + 247 given in the minimal example above and 913 is the sum of sum of rows 614 + 299 given in the minimal example.

Currently I am able to subset to a particular value but don't know how to sum based on these complex selections.  Can someone help?

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: Are you trying to find `library(dplyr);df %>% filter(TRU!='Total') %>% group_by_(.dots=names(df)[1:2]) %>% summarise(No_HH= sum(No_HH))`

Comment: @akrun the expected output is the value of rows 1 through 6,  wherein row 5 will be sum of 7 & 8 and row 5 will be sum of rows 9 & 10, row 4 will be sum of rows 5 & 6.  Similar the value of row 1 will be sum of rows that has Total in TRU column and Sub-District in Level column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(Level=='Sub-District' & TRU != 'Total')
#  District Subdistt   TRU        Level No_HH
#1 Adilabad    Tamsi Rural Sub-District   364
#2 Adilabad    Tamsi Urban Sub-District   913
```

If we need to get the same output by `sum`ming,

```
df %>%
    filter(!grepl('District', Level)) %>% 
    group_by(District, Subdistt,TRU) %>%
    summarise(No_HH= sum(No_HH)) %>%
    mutate(Level= 'Sub_District')
#  District Subdistt   TRU No_HH        Level
#     (chr)    (chr) (chr) (dbl)        (chr)
# 1 Adilabad    Tamsi Rural   364 Sub_District
# 2 Adilabad    Tamsi Urban   913 Sub_District
```